# Displaying songs by most played within last 30 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to display songs on my homepage sorted by the most played within the last 30 days. When a song is played this ajax function is called:

Note: I've bolded the section further down this page where I think the issue persists, but want to give info leading up to the problem just in case

```
function insertSongPlay(songID)

{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Album/InsertSongPlay/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "songID": songID }),
        success: function(data)
        {

            console.log("submitted");
            console.log(songID);
            //TODO: Indicate Success
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //TODO: Indicate Error
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Which corresponds to this JsonSubmit in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertSongPlay(int songID)
{
    try
    {
        EntityDataAccess.InsertSongPlay(songID);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And in my `entitydataaccess.cs` this method is used:

```
public static SongPlayDaily InsertSongPlay(int songID)
{
    using(var Context = GetContext())
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var currentSongPlay = Context.SongPlayDailies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SongID == songID && x.PlayDate == today);
        if (currentSongPlay != null)
            currentSongPlay.NumberOfPlays++;
        else
        {
            currentSongPlay = new SongPlayDaily();
            currentSongPlay.SongID = songID;
            currentSongPlay.PlayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            currentSongPlay.NumberOfPlays = 1;
            Context.SongPlayDailies.Add(currentSongPlay);
        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return currentSongPlay;
    }
}
```

Now on my homepage, **I believe this is where my problem is, but here is how I am trying to sort the albums on my homepage:**

```
public static List<Song> GetTopPlayedSongsByCount(int count)
{
    using(var Context = GetContext())
    {
        var lastDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30);
        var songIDs = Context.SongPlayDailies.Where(x => DateTime.Compare(x.PlayDate, lastDate) >= 0).GroupBy(x => x.SongID).Select(x => new { SongID = x.Key, NumberOfPlays = x.Sum(y => y.NumberOfPlays) }).OrderByDescending(x => x.NumberOfPlays).Take(count).Select(x => x.SongID).ToList();
        return Context.Songs.Include("Album").Include("Album.AccountInfo").Where(x => songIDs.Any(y => y == x.SongID)).ToList();
    }
}
```

However, the albums stay ordered in the date that I have uploaded them (from oldest to newest)

EDIT: Added Song.cs

```
namespace Domain.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Song
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Song()
        {
            this.DownloadHistories = new HashSet<DownloadHistory>();
            this.SongPlayDailies = new HashSet<SongPlayDaily>();
        }

        public int SongID { get; set; }
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Duration { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BPM { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> ApprovalFL { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<DownloadHistory> DownloadHistories { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SongPlayDaily> SongPlayDailies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Song class has a navigational property of type `List<SongPlayDailies>` ?

Comment: @Shyju hi, I edited the question to show my `Song.cs` class for you. I guess it's an `ICollection` though?

Comment: You are correct about where is the issue (GetTopPlayedSongsByCount method). You get ordered songIds from the DB, but the subsequent query is not ordered. It used where which filter only, but does not do any ordering. (Sorry I don't have more time now to make a proper answer)

Comment: To give a better performing answer, can you add your SongPlayDailies-class too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could integrate the second query into the first:

```
public static List<Song> GetTopPlayedSongsByCount(int count)
{
    using(var Context = GetContext())
    {
        var lastDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30);
        var result = Context.SongPlayDailies.Where(x => DateTime.Compare(x.PlayDate, lastDate) >= 0)
          .GroupBy(x => x.SongID)
          .Select(x => new { SongID = x.Key, NumberOfPlays = x.Sum(y => y.NumberOfPlays) })
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.NumberOfPlays)
          .Take(count)
          .Select(x => Context.Songs.Include("Album").Include("Album.AccountInfo").FirstOrDefault(y=>y.SongId==x.SongId))
          .Where(z=> z!=null).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not the best performing way though.